# UnsatisfiedLinkError nightmare

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I know that this question is already asked but I've no found any way to find a solution to my issue reading the existing code. Some my application users have experience about different kind of UnsatifiedLinkError:

1. Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mylib: findLibrary returned null
2. Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library mylib not found
3. Couldn't load mylib from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:
   /system/app/it.mycompany.myapp.apk,library
4. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: (The function exist and it's implemented)

I load my lib in the code using: System.oadLibrary("mylib");

I was never able to reproduce any of them.

Please have you some suggestions

Comment: where did you place 'mylib.so' before building .apk file?

Comment: May you post the full stack trace? Then should points which methods does not are correctly linked, or any native call crashes?

Answer (score 2):

Please check, if you can, under which versions of Android your users get these errors. It may be for example, that your "mylib" depends on some system library, which is found in newer versions of Android, but not on older ones. I had this e.g. when I made my native lib dependent on AssetManager - it was not supported under Android 2.2 "Froyo".

If you add a line like this to Application.mk in your jni folder, where you build your native lib:

APP_PLATFORM := android-8

it should throw errors during build, if you are using any functions or classes not supported under API level 8 (Android 2.2) - or adjust the level as you need.

Greg